# How do I add a short sound to a button?

Tags: objective-c, audio, button

I would like my button to make a short ding sound and randomly switch between one of two locations after each click.  When I tried the code below the program stopped working.  The code worked fine before I inserted the systemSound ID code.

```
- (IBAction)CountRedClicks:(id)sender{
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
RedCounter = RedCounter + 1;
RandNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 2;
if (RandNumber == 1) {
    CGRect frame = RedButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 128;
    frame.origin.y = 458;
    RedButton.frame = frame;
}
if (RandNumber == 1) {
    CGRect frame = GreenButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 422;
    frame.origin.y = 458;
    GreenButton.frame = frame;
}
if (RandNumber == 2) {
    CGRect frame = RedButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 422;
    frame.origin.y = 458;
    RedButton.frame = frame;
}
if (RandNumber == 2) {
    CGRect frame = GreenButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 128;
    frame.origin.y = 458;
    GreenButton.frame = frame;
}
if (RedCounter == 10) {
    RedCounter = 0;
    PointsCounter = PointsCounter + 1;
    PointsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", PointsCounter];
    RedButton.hidden = true;
    GreenButton.hidden = true;
    PointsLabel.hidden = false;
    ResetButton.hidden = false;

    if (PointsCounter == 3){
        [PointsLabel setText:@"GREAT JOB!"];
        ResetButton.hidden = true;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you describe "stopped working" in terms of symptoms, error messages, crashes, or something?

Comment: So to clarify, when I run the program with the code as is, the build succeeds, but when I click on the button, it takes me to a screen that says this:
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {@autoreleasepool {return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: could you log out the soundFile variable, to let us know if it is a correct path. If this is null, then you will run into an error. Secondly, the method you are using has been noted as having mp3 support issues, as per this link. http://www.geeklane.com/2009/04/07/audioservicescreatesystemsoundid-weirdness/  Try converting the sound to a .wav or a .caf file and then try with that.

Comment: From Xcode Docu: Sound files that you play using this function must be:

No longer than 30 seconds in duration
In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format
Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

Comment: Does this work on a real device? You should test your code on a real iOS device--not the simulator.

Comment: I will try to convert the sound.  It is a short sound, just a few seconds in length, so that shouldn't be the problem.  I have not yet tried it on a device either, so can try that.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with your mp3 file. Here I can play one mp3 with no error.

Comment: I just tried the systemSoundID code in another program and it worked there, so the mp3 file seems fine.  I'm puzzled why I can't get this to work in my current program.  What do I have to do to log out the soundFile variable, per Bergarsm's suggestion?